# Using AWS, EC2, can't reach port 1433 for sql server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, port, amazon-vpc

we're using two AWS EC2 instances, win 2012 servers, one for MS SQL Server and one for IIS.  IIS is unable to reach port 1433 on the SQL Server.  Here's what we've tried:

- Checked VPC setting and no rules blocking access
- Servers on the same subnet
- Servers in the same availability zone (not that it matters)
- Using netstat -a -b -n, can see that the port is open and listening and is associated with SQL Server app

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a bit to figure this out.

While the netstat showed that the port was open, the Win 2012 server advanced firewall was blocking the port.  So, important to note here that Windows Firewall overrules whatever is in netstat

All we needed to do was create a new rule to open that port, and then we tested via a cool new command line command called test-netconnection command: "tnc xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -port 1433"

it is now showing as open

Comment: Is this you sharing what you learned, or did you work on the answer yourself 3 minutes after posting?

Comment: lol, just sharing.  wish I figured it out in 3 minutes.  It took me several days and there were some answers in the forums, but nothing exactly on point